Custom Print Option Not Displaying for Payslip in Odoo
I am trying to create a custom payslip report in Odoo and add it to the print button on the payslip form view. I have followed the steps to create the module, define the report, and bind it to the hr.payslip model, but the new print option does not appear in the interface.
Here are the details of what I have done:
In Manifest File (manifest.py)
  'depends': ['account', 'sale_management', 'hr_contract','hr_holiday',],

XML Files
wcm_pay_slip_report.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<template id="wcm_pay_slip_report">
   <t t-call="web.html_container">
        <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="doc">
            <t t-call="hr_payroll.report_payslipdocument"/>
        <main>
            <div class="page">
                <h2 class="text-center" style="background-color: #336699; color: white; padding: 10px;">FICHE DE
                    PAIE
                </h2>

                <table class="table table-sm mt32" style="width: 100%; border: 1px solid #336699;">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="padding: 10px;">
                            <strong>Employeur</strong>
                            <br/>
                            Num Emplé:

                        </td>
                        <td class="text-right" style="padding: 10px;">
                            Mois:

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2" style="padding: 10px; text-align: center;">
                            <img t-att-src="" alt="Logo" style="width: 150px;"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="padding: 10px;">
                            Raison Sociale:

                            Adresse:

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

                <table class="table table-sm mt32" style="width: 100%; border: 1px solid #336699;">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="padding: 10px;">
                            <strong>Salarié</strong>
                            <br/>
                            Nom:

                            Date de naissance:

                        </td>
                        <td style="padding: 10px;">
                            Salaire de base:

                            Nº de compte:

                            Mode de paiement:

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

                <table class="table table-sm mt32" style="width: 100%; border: 1px solid #336699;">
                    <thead style="background-color: #336699; color: white;">
                        <tr>
                            <th style="padding: 5px;">Code</th>
                            <th style="padding: 5px;">Désignation</th>
                            <th style="padding: 5px;">Nbre/Taux</th>
                            <th style="padding: 5px;">Montant</th>
                            <th style="padding: 5px;">Gains</th>
                            <th style="padding: 5px;">Retenues</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <!--<tbody>
                      <tr t-foreach="payslip.details_by_salary_rule_category" t-as="line">
                           <td style="padding: 5px;"><t t-esc="line.code"/></td>
                           <td style="padding: 5px;"><t t-esc="line.name"/></td>
                           <td style="padding: 5px;"><t t-esc="line.quantity"/></td>
                           <td style="padding: 5px;"><t t-esc="line.amount"/></td>
                           <td style="padding: 5px;"><t t-esc="line.total"/></td>
                           <td style="padding: 5px;"><t t-esc="line.total_deduction"/></td>
                       </tr>
                   </tbody>!-->
                </table>

                <table class="table table-sm mt32" style="width: 100%; border: 1px solid #336699;">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="padding: 10px;">
                            <strong>SALAIRE IMPOSABLE</strong>
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-right" style="padding: 10px;">

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="padding: 10px;">
                            <strong>TOTAL GAINS</strong>
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-right" style="padding: 10px;">

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="padding: 10px;">
                            <strong>TOTAL RETENUES</strong>
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-right" style="padding: 10px;">

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="padding: 10px;">
                            <strong>NET A PAYER</strong>
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-right" style="padding: 10px;">

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </main>
     </t>
    </t>
</template>


<record id="wcm_pay_slip_report_action" model="ir.actions.report">
    <field name="name">Fiche de Paie</field>
    <field name="model">hr.payslip</field>
    <field name="report_type">qweb-pdf</field>
    <field name="report_name">wsl_wcm_report.wcm_pay_slip_report</field>
    <field name="report_file">wsl_wcm_report.wcm_pay_slip_report</field>
    <field name="print_report_name">('Fiche de Paie- %s' % (object.employee_id.name))</field>
    <field name="binding_model_id" ref="hr_holiday.model_hr_payslip"/>
    <field name="binding_type">report</field>

</record>

the template and the action are in the same file but here's the action snipetcode
<record id="wcm_pay_slip_report_action" model="ir.actions.report">
    <field name="name">Fiche de Paie</field>
    <field name="model">hr.payslip</field>
    <field name="report_type">qweb-pdf</field>
    <field name="report_name">wsl_wcm_report.wcm_pay_slip_report</field>
    <field name="report_file">wsl_wcm_report.wcm_pay_slip_report</field>
    <field name="print_report_name">('Fiche de Paie- %s' % (object.employee_id.name))</field>
    <field name="binding_model_id" ref="hr_holiday.model_hr_payslip"/>
    <field name="binding_type">report</field>

</record>

I have tried with multiple HR modules, but the issue persists. Any guidance on what might be going wrong or what additional steps I should take to troubleshoot this issue would be greatly appreciated.

The print action menu was removed intentionally by Odoo in hr.payslip model, check the get_views function
The binding model ID should be  hr_payroll.model_hr_payslip.
